# Javascript: Function that retries with setTimeout

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, settimeout

I have a function `downloadItem` that may fail for network reasons, I want to be able to retry it a few times before actually rejecting that item. The retries need to be with a timeout since if there is a network issue there is no point in retrying immediately.

Here is what I have so far:

```
function downloadItemWithRetryAndTimeout(url, retry, failedReason) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        try {
            if (retry < 0 && failedReason != null) reject(failedReason);

            downloadItem(url);
            resolve();
        } catch (e) {
            setTimeout(function() {
                downloadItemWithRetryAndTimeout(url, retry - 1, e);
            }, 1000);
        }
    });
}
```

Obviously this will fail since the second (and on) time I call `downloadItemWithRetryAndTimeout` I don't return a promise as required.

How do I make it work correctly with that second promise?

P.S. incase it matters the code is running in NodeJS.

Comment: maybe using promise does not fit your scenario. I don't get why people suddenly use promises for every single async case.

Comment: I don't have to use a promise, you have any solution without a promise?

Comment: @webduvet: because that's what promises are made for: async cases with a single result. And it does fit this scenario very well.

Comment: @AlexD: Is your `downloadItem` function really synchronous? I think it should return a promise.

Comment: @alexd with Bluebird you can use [Promise.delay](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#delayint-ms---promise) and [Promise.try](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#promisetryfunction-fn--arraydynamicdynamic-arguments--dynamic-ctx----promise)

Comment: @Bergi, right, but if you need your result only once, and only in one case and you are not facing any nested callbacks problem, using promise library  ads just unnecessary complexity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've got two ideas:

Move the promise out side of the iterated function downloadItemWithRetryAndTimeout - now resolve() will available to all iterations:

```
function downloadWrapper(url, retry) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        function downloadItemWithRetryAndTimeout(url, retry, failedReason) {

            try {
                if (retry < 0 && failedReason != null)
                    reject(failedReason);

                downloadItem(url);
                resolve();
            } catch (e) {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    downloadItemWithRetryAndTimeout(url, retry - 1, e);
                }, 1000);
            }

        }

        downloadItemWithRetryAndTimeout(url, retry, null);
    });
}
```

This solution works, but it's an anti pattern as it breaks the promise chain:
As each iteration returns a promise, just resolve the promise, and use .then to resolve the previous promise, and so on:

```
function downloadItemWithRetryAndTimeout(url, retry, failedReason) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        try {
            if (retry < 0 && failedReason != null)
                reject(failedReason);

            downloadItem(url);
            resolve();
        } catch (e) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                downloadItemWithRetryAndTimeout(url, retry - 1, e).then(function () {
                    resolve();
                });
            }, 1000);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I really like your first solution! I've changed it a bit since inside the promise after declaring the inner function you have to also call it once. I'll try it now

Comment: Sloppy me - forgot to run the function - fixed.

Comment: Please avoid the [promise constructor antipattern](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572)

Comment: @Bergi - thanks. Didn't think that it falls to the same deferred trap.

Answer (score 3):

There is no need to create new promises to handle this. Assuming `downloadItem` is synchronous and returns a promise, simply return the result of calling it, along with a `catch` to call `downloadItemWithRetryAndTimeout` recursively.

```
function wait(n) { return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, n)); }

function downloadItemWithRetryAndTimeout(url, retry) {
  if (retry < 0) return Promise.reject();

  return downloadItem(url) . 
    catch(() => wait(1000) . 
      then(() => downloadItemWithRetryAndTimeout(url, retry - 1)
  );
}
```

Some might find the following slightly cleaner:

```
function downloadItemWithRetryAndTimeout(url, retry) {
  return function download() {
    return --retry < 0 ? Promise.reject() :
      downloadItem(url) . catch(() => wait(1000) . then(download));
  }();
}
```

Comment: It'd make more sense to do it through a general retry method `const retry = (fn, retries = 3) => fn().catch(e => retries <= 0? Promise.reject(e) : retry(fn, retries - 1))` and compose it with timeouts: `const delay = ms => new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, ms))` and `const delayError = (fn, ms) => fn().catch(e => delay(ms).then(y => Promise.reject(e)))`. Then the code becomes `const downloadWithRetryAndTimeout = retry(delayError(download, 1000))` or something like that.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Thanks for this elegant decomposition.

Answer (score 2):

@BenjaminGruenbaum comment on @user663031 is fantastic but there's a slight error because this:

```
const delayError = (fn, ms) => fn().catch(e => delay(ms).then(y => Promise.reject(e)))
```

should actually be:

```
const delayError = (fn, ms) => () => fn().catch(e => delay(ms).then(y => Promise.reject(e)))
```

so it will return a function, not a promise. It's a tricky error that's hard to solve so I'm posting on here in case anyone needs it. Here's the whole thing:

```
const retry = (fn, retries = 3) => fn().catch(e => retries <= 0 ? Promise.reject(e) : retry(fn, retries - 1))
const delay = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms))
const delayError = (fn, ms) => () => fn().catch(e => delay(ms).then(y => Promise.reject(e)))
retry(delayError(download, 1000))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function downloadItemWithRetryAndTimeout(url, retry) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        var tryDownload = function(attempts) {
            try {
                downloadItem(url);
                resolve();
            } catch (e) {
                if (attempts == 0)  {
                    reject(e);
                } else {
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        tryDownload(attempts - 1);
                    }, 1000);
                }
            }
        };
        tryDownload(retry);
    });
}
```